# OpenCart pass data to children module

Tags: opencart

Basically what i'm trying to do is to pass some data from "parent" controller to the controller of its children module, for example:

*header* controller

```php
$this->children = array(
    'module/newslettersubscribe'
);
```

*newslettersubscribe* controller

```php
public function index() {
   // Use here data from the header controller
}
```

Is that even possible to do?

Comment: It is possible for example if you store that data into the session. Then you can retrieve that data anywhere within the code, even in different controllers - until the session times out. The question is why do you need to do this? From the question itself I can see there is some mistake in the architecture...

Comment: For example, i have slider module on the category layout and what do i need to do is to show different images for specific category.
So first idea that i have is to pass data (images) from the category controller to the slider controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here the approach is incorrect. You should edit only the slider controller and check whether there is a `path` variable available in the GET (query string), e.g.:

```
if (!empty($this->request->get['path'])) { /* ... */ }
```

If it is you can now extract the categories from it's value (which is e.g. `1_12_36`):

```
if (!empty($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $category_ids = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
}
```

Now knowing the category IDs (or the category path) you can display the appropriate images only using whatever code you made up.